# How to append to existing flag in scons

Tags: scons

I'm using Hi-Tech C compiler and wish to use Scons to build my projects. The compiler executable is `picc.exe`. It has similar semantics as GCC, but not all.

I've set the default too as GCC and try to modify from there. The output from executing `env.Program('main.c')`:

```
picc -o main.o -c
```

However, in Hi-Tech C, the `-o` flag means output file, e.g. `-Oc:\project\output\first`

How do I append to `-o`, so that it will output to become:

```
picc -omain.o -c
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you have above. Is the issue that picc needs there to be no whitespace between the "-o" and the desired output filename?

Comment: Oh, and you should probably mention what version of SCons, and what platform (looks like windows from what you have above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So poking around in the "Tools" directory of the SCons install finds these definitions:

```
cc.py:    env['CCCOM']     = '$CC -o $TARGET -c $CFLAGS $CCFLAGS $_CCCOMCOM $SOURCES'
cc.py:    env['SHCCCOM']   = '$SHCC -o $TARGET -c $SHCFLAGS $SHCCFLAGS $_CCCOMCOM $SOURCES'
c++.py:    env['CXXCOM']     = '$CXX -o $TARGET -c $CXXFLAGS $CCFLAGS $_CCCOMCOM $SOURCES'
c++.py:    env['SHCXXCOM']   = '$SHCXX -o $TARGET -c $SHCXXFLAGS $SHCCFLAGS $_CCCOMCOM $SOURCES'
link.py:    env['SHLINKCOM']   = '$SHLINK -o $TARGET $SHLINKFLAGS $SOURCES $_LIBDIRFLAGS $_LIBFLAGS'
link.py:    env['LINKCOM']     = '$LINK -o $TARGET $LINKFLAGS $SOURCES $_LIBDIRFLAGS $_LIBFLAGS'
```

So perhaps all you need to do is override these elements in your env with versions that adjoin the -o and the $TARGET. I think you might need to place braces around the variables, so something like:

```
env['CCCOM'] = '$CC -o${TARGET} -c $CFLAGS $CCFLAGS $_CCCOMCOM $SOURCES'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Alternatively I should just make a custom builder instead of overriding the default.